# HTML content after a particular tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have a String with HTML formated text (not a whole webpage).

How can I get all the HTML content after a particular tag using Jsoup?

To be more concret. Assuming I have the following string:

```
String input = "<div>a</div><p>b</p><strong>c</strong>";
```

I would like to get:

```
String output = "<p>b</p><strong>c</strong>";
```

Hence I am doing

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(input); // parse
Element p = doc.select("p"); // select p
```

And I have a hard time firguring out how to output what after p. Let assume for simplicity that p is unique.

Another input/output (as asked):

```
String input = "<br /><strong>a</strong><strong>b</strong><p>c</p><div>d</div><br />";
String output = "<p>c</p><div>d</div><br />";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you give a few more examples of input/output text?  i don't think there's enough here yet to fully answer your question.

Comment: Of course. Here you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code - hope it helps you a bit:

```
String input = "<div>a</div><p>b</p><strong>c</strong>";


Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
Elements elements = doc.select("p ~ *");

Elements group = new Elements();
group.add(elements.first().previousElementSibling());


for( Element element : elements )
{
    group.add(element);
}

// You can work with 'group' too
String output = group.toString();
```

**Output:**

*example 1:*

```
<p>b</p>
<strong>c</strong>
```

*example 2:*

```
<p>c</p>
<div>
 d
</div>
<br />
```

Comment: Great! :-) But keep in mind: `p ~ *` selects everything _after_ the `p`-tag.